# Find JS object/hash with specific key-value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a JS object with multiple objects with the same properties.

EDIT: I modified the outer braces to square brackets to reflect what the actual object is. The accepted answer is in the comments.

```
var object = [
   {
      id: 1,
      foo: 'bar'
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      foo: 'bar2'
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      foo: 'bar3'
   },
   {
      id: 4,
      foo: 'bar4'
   }
];
```

How would I get the object with a specific id e.g. `id == 1`, something similar to the Rails method `ActiveRecord::Relation.where(id: 1)`?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript!

Comment: My bad, I was in a rush and just forgot that the surrounding object is an array with indices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make an array of objects for search and try this like,

```
var object = [{ // make array by using [ and ]
    id: 1,
    foo: 'bar'
}, {
    id: 2,
    foo: 'bar2'
}, {
    id: 3,
    foo: 'bar3'
}, {
    id: 4,
    foo: 'bar4'
}];
function searchByKey(obj, key) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj[i].id == key) {
            return obj[i];
        }
    }
    return "Not found";
}
console.log(searchByKey(object,1));
console.log(searchByKey(object,4));
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/d7bg6oud/)